# symfony apache configuration error, controller not getting called

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, httpd.conf

I configured my `/etc/apache/httpd.conf` as said in the `getting started` tutorial :

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/innobo/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/var/www/innobo/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /var/www/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/var/www/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
 Alias /uploads /var/www/innobo/web/uploads
  <Directory "/var/www/innobo/web/uploads">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I open `localhost:8080`  in web browser, it works fine. but when I try to open anything else like `localhost:8080/poster` , it throws a `404`. And that's not a 404 redirected by symfony, it's the default one generated by apache! That means apache is not sending the request to my controller i.e. `/var/www/innobo/web/index.php`. I tried the same on another computer, it works fine. there the request reaches controller and everything works as expected. Where can the fault lie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If app.php/poster is working, this could depend by a setting in `settings.yml` (guessing you are working with secure mode in backend side):

```
prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         false
```

If this is the problem, you have to change to `true` the `no_script_name` parameter.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like mod_rewrite isn't on/working. try `localhost:8080/app.php/poster`

You should also run the symfony check script. By default, you can find it it /web/config.php, so you should be able to access it by putting `localhost:8080/config.php` in you browser

Comment: then it is definitely mod_rewrite. Look up how to install/enable it for whatever flavor of server your using.